# How to generate the DDL for all the Users in a Snowflake Account?

Tags: sql, get, ddl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, generate

Is there a way to get the DDL for all the users in a Snowflake Account ?

I see the following URL says there are about 10 items that the get_ddl supports currently :

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl.html

If there's nothing out there, then I'll use the traditional Concatenation of data and strings to generate the commands like select 'create user ' || username || ... from...

Please let me know.

Thanks
Jitz

Comment: Thanks Suzy, Mike and Greg for your responses and support! 
Appreciate your help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

At this time, I don't believe there's built-in Snowflake functionality for this.  A script, like you mentioned, would work to fill the need in the meantime.

There is a feature request called "Expand GET_DDL" on the Ideas page and that you could upvote (and add a comment that you are particularly interested in Users):  https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas

Answer (score 0):

As Suzy has explained there isn't an option that exists natively at the moment. So your best bet is probably to take the approach you have outlined:

- do a show users in account
- cycle through that with something like: table(result_scan(last_query_id()))

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use the traditional concatenation technique, I wrote a stored procedure to automate running all of the resulting rows from that approach. You can find it here:

[How to drop temp tables created in snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882865/how-to-drop-temp-tables-created-in-snowflake/59890595#59890595)

You can feed it your select as the only parameter...

> select 'create user ' || username || ... from...

Make sure that the column is called "SQL_COMMAND", and the stored procedure in the link above will run all the resulting SQL statements one at a time.